# Factorial Inequality Proof

Tags: number-theory

I need some help proving the following fact about factorials.

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive integers. Prove that if $a > b$, then $a! > b!$.

Comment: Um.... what is the definition $a!$ and $b!$?  This is a *VERY* easy thing to prove.

Comment: And false if you remove the $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ constraint.

Comment: $a > b, (a-1) > (b-1), \dots, (a-(b-1)) > 1$. Multiply all together.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio true.  But if you remove the a,b in Z^+ constraint you need a different definition of factorial.

Comment: Second hint:  Do $a!$ and $b!$ have any factors in common?

Comment: Have a look at the definition of $a!$ and $b!$ and if this is too abstract at first, try it for some concrete $a$ and $b$. Maybe $a=3$, $b=5$ or $b=6$. You should notice something.

Comment: @fleablood: like $$ n!\stackrel{\text{def}}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^n e^{-z}\,dz, $$ of course.

Comment: Oh, I guess if $0! = 1$ is part of the definition (which it usually but not always is) I guess you don't need a different definition.

Comment: @fleablood then prove it.

Comment: HINT: $a!/b!=?$. Second hint: if $a>b$ then $a=b+k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N_{>0}$.

Comment: @fleablood the common factor between a! and b! is b! itself, right? That's the thing you tried to say?

Comment: Try doing this: if $a>b$ then $a=b+k$ where $k>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show a stronger inequality: $a! > b\cdot b!$ (1)
$a = b+k, k \ge 1 \implies a! = (b+k)! = (b+k)(b+k-1)\cdots (b+1)b(b-1)\cdots 1= (b+k)(b+k-1)\cdots (b+1)b! > (b+1)^kb! > b^kb! > bb! \ge b!$. Thus (1) is proven.

Answer (score 1):

if $a>b \iff \dfrac{a}{b}>1$ then let $p=a-b$

$\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{a}k}{\prod_{k=1}^{b}k}=\dfrac{\prod_{k=1}^{b+p}k}{\prod_{k=1}^{b}k}=\prod_{k=b+1}^{a}k\;>1 \implies a!>b!$

Answer (score 1):

If $a>b$ then $$a!=a \cdot (a-1) \cdot \ \dots \ \cdot (b+1) \cdot  b \cdot (b-1) \cdot \ \dots \ \cdot 1$$
so we would have
$$b!=\frac{a!}{a \cdot (a-1) \cdot \ \dots \ \cdot(b+1)} < a! \implies b! < a!.$$